# Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE

Tags: android

After installation of latest 2.3 beta version my studio is giving error that plugin version too old....and finally it leads too failure of gradle build...
The following is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.atharv.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Could you post the error stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your build tools dependency in your project level build.gradle file, not the module level build.gradle that you posted.

If you are using Android Studio, hit the shift key twice to open up a 'search everywhere' dialog and type

> build.gradle

You should see two files, one for your project and one for your app module. After that, you just need to change the build tools classpath to the latest version

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-beta2'

Your project level build.gradle file should look something like this:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        // Build Tools
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-beta2'
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Also just in case any future users see this post, you can find every release of the Android build tools here: https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/ and update the dependency as needed. The latest version at the time of this posting is

> 2.3.0-beta2

Answer (score 0):

Your plugin must match that specified by the gradle version

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html